# Time Profiler: Quickly expand tree

Tags: xcode, xcode-instruments

Is there any way to quickly expand all the tree in the Time Profiler (Xcode Instrument).

Currently, I have to click on every nested disclosure indicator, but I guess, there is a way to expand all the tree to see what's taking most of the time.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Option-click the disclosure triangle to expand the whole tree. This works on any instrument that has a call tree view, not just the Time Profiler instrument.